# Insert value into input field using id locator

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I use this code with Java and Selenium in Angular SPA app:

```
    WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 25);
    WebElement webElement = webDriverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(inputId)));
    webElement.clear();  // First we delete the old value in case if this is a spinner
    webElement.sendKeys(value);
```

Usually it's working fine in normal tests with Chrome. But in headless mode it's not finding the input field by id. Do you know is there other day to implement a lister to locate the input field?

Comment: in headless you can try to put some thread.sleep and check if you see consistent behavior

Comment: yes, but in general is there some other solution to implement a listener?

Comment: listeners are for event generation, they will just let you know if the code did not work. they can not help you with head or with headless issue.

Comment: If there is a spinner, try waiting for spinner to not be displayed. The input field may be present but the spinner is on top of it.

Comment: `presenceOfElementLocated()` just tells you if the element is in the DOM, not if it's interactable. Use `visibilityOfElementLocated()` instead and see if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Add the visiblity check in your code,

```
By appct = By.id("inputId");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(appct));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(driver.findElements(appct)));
driver.findElement(appct).sendKeys("jayanth");
```